# Regular Expression in Oracle with REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to get the email address part of a string. 
For example if the string is

> "your name(your@name.com)" aaa@bbb.com

then I want to get only

> aaaa@bbb.com

basically if I can remove the string within

> ""

then it does the trick. I am using below regular expression with  `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('"your name(abc@dd.com)" aaa@bbb.com',
             '([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-])+@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+[.])+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+')
```

kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply indicate that the match must occur at the end of the string, using `$` anchor.

```
with t1(col) as(
   select '"your name(your@name.com)" aaa@bbb.com' from dual
)

select regexp_substr(col, '[[:alnum:]._%-]+@[[:alnum:]._%-]+\.com$') as res
  from t1
```

Result:

```
RES
-----------
aaa@bbb.com
```

Comment: Cool this works. Thanks. But would you be able to give a REGEX which will eliminate all strings within double quotes

Comment: @NuwanDammika Seems like a different question. So please, do not hesitate to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question with clear explanation of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Its not a new question, the idea is to remove the text within double quotes("). I have mentioned it in the original question as a suggestion. Quote _"if I can remove the string within "" then it does the trick"_ end quote.

Comment: @NuwanDammika you also wrote `I want to get only aaaa@bbb.com` you have to state explicitly what you want to eliminate any kid of speculations and unnecessary long comments.

Comment: isn't remove within double quotes and keep the  remaining refer to the same. I think so. Any way I accept this as the answer. Thank.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need something more along the lines of:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('"your name(abc@dd.com)" aaa@bbb.com','[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}')
```

Things like `[.]` doesnt really make sense, dot matches any character and the square brackets is a kind of "OR" statement where any character inside can go in that place, but in your case you actually want to match the literal dot so you need to escape that `\.` not sure how oracle handles the escapes, you might need to double escape them.

Comment: Thanks for quick response,  I will check,

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  REGEXP_SUBSTR(email, '[A-Za-z0-9\_\-\.]+@\w+\.\w+', 1, 2) AS cleaned_email
FROM
(
        SELECT  '"your name(your@name.com)" aaa@bbb.com'      AS email FROM DUAL UNION ALL
        SELECT  '"your name(your.name@name.com)" aaa@bbb.com' AS email FROM DUAL
)
;
```

Comment: This will still give me the email address within double quotes,which I already getting. Anyway thanks for quick response.:)

Comment: @NuwanDammika I changed the occurrence to second. Now it should be fine.